# Stop Threads created by foreach

Tags: c#, .net

well, i make a loop that makes a lot of threads, see:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

    Class h = new Class(dgvRow.Cells["name"].Value.ToString());

    Thread trdmyClass = new Thread(h.SeeInfoAboutName);
    trdmyClass.IsBackground = true;
    trdmyClass.Start();
}
```

This is working fine, creating the threads that i need, but i want to stop all this threads (using `Thread.Abort()`), in one time when i click on a button for e.g.
How can i do this?

Comment: You named one of your classes "Class"?

Comment: Why do you want to murder threads? That's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't use `Thread.Abort()`, it can be very dangerous. Instead, you should provide some way to signal to the threads that they are canceled. Each thread would then periodically check whether it's canceled and end if it was.

One way to do this would be to use [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx), which does exactly that. The framework methods that support cancellation work with this type too.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
// field to keep CancellationTokenSource:
CancellationTokenSource m_cts;

// in your method:

m_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    Class h = new Class(dgvRow.Cells["name"].Value.ToString());

    Thread trdmyClass = new Thread(() => h.SeeInfoAboutName(m_cts.Token));
    trdmyClass.IsBackground = true;
    trdmyClass.Start();
}

//somewhere else, where you want to cancel the threads:
m_cts.Cancel();

// the SeeInfoAboutName() method
public void SeeInfoAboutName(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: And to start the m_cts again?

Comment: If you want to start another bunch of threads, create a new `CancellationTokenSource` and use that.

Comment: If you think this answer actually solved your question, you should [accpet it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use Thread.Abort.  It can have some very nasty consequences.  What you should be doing is keeping track of the threads you create by putting them into a list.  You can then use a ManualResetEvent class.  The threads should check if the reset was raised or not periodically and if it has been set, they should cleanup and exit.  I use the WaitOne method will a millisecond timeout and then check the return value to allow threads to run in a loop.  If true is returned the signal is set and you can exit the loop or otherwise return from your thread.  If you're using .Net 4, you can also use a CancelationToken as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx

Read more about the issues with Thread.Abort here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx

EDIT:  I use a ManualResetEvent as its thread safe and you could use it to syncronize the processing in the threads, for example if you're doing a producer / consumer pattern. A volatile boolean could be used as well.  I recommend keeping the threads in a list in case you need to wait for them to complete, so you can Join on each one.  This may or may not be applicable to your problem though.  Its usually a good idea, especially if you're exiting, to Join all your threads to allow them to finish any cleanup they may be doing.

Comment: Why would you use a `ManualResetEvent`? Isn't a `bool` field enough? Also, why would you keep the `Thread`s in a list? You don't seem to use it.

Comment: Boolean field is read and written atomically by clr so ManualResetEvent is not needed for that.

Comment: Reads of `bool` are guaranteed to be atomic, so they can't change while you're reading it. But the read might be from a CPU cache that is not up to date. To avoid that, you can use `volatile` field.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the threads in a List, and then loop through the list and stop them.

Comment: @Robson Those are thread objects. Any object can go in a list. You can make a List<Thread> and add them one by one when you create them.